# How to create custom REST API endpoint correctly

Tags: rest, api, endpoint

Suppose we have customers: /api/customers (/api/customers/{id})

With the following content:

```
[{
    name: "Mike",
    age: 20,
    amount: 300
},
{
    name: "John",
    age: 30,
    amount: 600
}]
```

But there are different tasks when you have to perform various data manipulations.

Suppose we need to display the client who spent the most (in the "amount" field).

What the endpoint should look like for this request?

I have a few suggestions how to do this, please correct me:

```
1. /api/customers/spent-more

2. /api/customers-spent-more

3. /api/customers?action=spent-more
```

How do you perform similar tasks, share experiences

Comment: Even though you already have found a solution, I'd want to clarify that the spelling of the URI is not of relevance in a REST architecture system. Clients shouldn't interpret URIs and only use the URIs it is provided by servers. Clients will determine whether to invoke such a URI based on an accompanying link relation name and a text summarizing the content. The accepted answer is thereby misleading as it states that `/api/customers/spent-more` is the correct solution when actually there is no wright or wrong. This question should have been closed due to attracting opinionated answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct endpoint would be:

> 1. /api/customers/spent-more

You could then pass in any additional query parameters as part of your request string.

In theory, you could use:

> 3. /api/customers?action=spent-more

and have a switch on the backend that returns the desired data depending on which action was sent, but the advantages and disadvantages of each method are dependent upon your architecture and how many actions you will end up with. I would say that traditional MVC architecture would dictate the former.

Answer (score 0):

Provide sorting and limit as parameters

```
/api/customers?sort_by=amount&limit=1&order=desc
```

Response is one customer which has spent most. Of course the approach can be used for other use-cases as well.